# Read variables from static method into main method as argument when calling the method

Tags: java, static-methods

I am having trouble on fixing my program, In my last two lines of code, when I call the static method for surfaceGravity, the compiler complains about the argument radius with the statement "incompatible: double cannot be converted to a double[]" and when I call the static method for display, the compiler complains about the argument g with the statement "cannot find symbol". How do I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class GravityV1{

// calculate surface gravity static method
public static double[] surfaceGravity(double G, double[] M, double[] r){

    // surface gravity variable
    double[] g = new double[M.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < g.length; i++){

        // equation for calculating surface gravity
        g[i] = (G * M[i]) / Math.pow(r[i], 2);
    }

    // return statement
    return g;
}

// displaying static method

// write results to text file static method
public static String[] writeToFile() throws IOException{

    int index = 0;
    String[] data = new String[index];
    File filename = new File("/Users/timothylee/Gravity1.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(filename);
    while(inFile.hasNext()){

        data[index] = inFile.next( );

        index++;

    }

    inFile.close();
    return data;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    // declare array for months
    String[] Planets = new String[8];

    // initialize array
    Planets [0] = "Mercury";
    Planets [1] = "Venus";
    Planets [2] = "Earth";
    Planets [3] = "Mars";
    Planets [4] = "Jupiter";
    Planets [5] = "Saturn";
    Planets [6] = "Uranus";
    Planets [7] = "Neptune";

    // declare array for mass
    double[] mass = new double[8];

    // initialize array
    mass [0] = 3.30E23;
    mass [1] = 4.869E24;
    mass [2] = 5.97E24;
    mass [3] = 6.4219E23;
    mass [4] = 1.900E27;
    mass [5] = 5.68E26;
    mass [6] = 8.683E25;
    mass [7] = 1.0247E26;

    // declare array for diameter
    double[] diameter = new double[8];

    // initialize array
    diameter [0] = 4880;
    diameter [1] = 12103.6;
    diameter [2] = 12756;
    diameter [3] = 6794;
    diameter [4] = 142984;
    diameter [5] = 120536;
    diameter [6] = 51118;
    diameter [7] = 49532;


    double[] surfaceG = new double[8];
    // // convert to radius

    // declare radius variable
    double radius = 0;

    // for each loop for displaying
    for(double calc : diameter){

        // calculation for converting to radius
        radius =  calc / 2;
    }

    // // calculate surface gravity

    // declare and initialize universal gravity constant;
    double G = 6.67384 * Math.pow(10, -11);

    // call surface gravity method
    surfaceGravity(G, mass, radius);

    // display result
    display(Planets, radius, mass, g);
}
}
```

Comment: on a side note,my advice would be to put the planets names, mass and diameter into a enum and call on the enum a function to calculate the g or even save the G since it's all static dana
more efficient and easier to use than this here is a link with example: http://snipplr.com/view/42422/

Comment: The name of the variables are case sensitive, the last argument you use in your call to display() is wrong, should be 'G'

Answer (score 1):

To fix your **first** problem you should replace your code:

```
// declare radius variable
double radius = 0;

// for each loop for displaying
for(double calc : diameter){

    // calculation for converting to radius
    radius =  calc / 2;
}
```

with this:

```
// declare radius variable
double radius[] = new double[diameter.length];

// for each loop for displaying
for (int i = 0; i < radius.length; i++){

   // calculation for converting to radius
   radius[i] =  diameter[i] / 2;
}
```

And to fix **second** problem you should replace:

```
// call surface gravity method
surfaceGravity(G, mass, radius);
```

with this:

```
// call surface gravity method
double[] g = surfaceGravity(G, mass, radius);
```

Answer (score 0):

as the compiler says your `radius` variable is type of `double` but your function requires array of doubles

Answer (score 0):

```
double[] surfaceGravity(double G, double[] M, double[] r)
```

you are calling this function with wrong type of parameter:

```
surfaceGravity(G, mass, radius);
```

`radius` is primitive type variable with `double`. The third parameter to be passed must be an array. So you must pass pass an array in place of radius. Change your method's parameter type:

```
double[] surfaceGravity(double G, double[] M, double r)
```

> , the compiler complains about the argument g with the statement
>   "cannot find symbol". How do I fix this?

you haven't declared any variable `g` in your class context or `main()` function context. So declare it with relevant type and in proper context.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
public static double[] surfaceGravity(double G, double[] M, double[] r){
```

You declare that r should be of type double array, but in your main method here:

```
double radius = 0;
```

You declare radius to be of type double. Clearly these two are incompatible.

Also, in your main method when you call:

```
surfaceGravity(G, mass, radius);
```

Which returns a double array, you never assign the return value to anything. You can resolve this by saying:

```
double[] g = surfaceGravity(G, mass, radius);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a `double` into a `double[]` variable, which doesn't make sense.

```
double[] surfaceGravity(double G, double[] M, double[] r)
```

in prototype, '`r`' is an annary. However, `radius` in '`surfaceGravity(G, mass, radius);`' is `double` primitive.